# Save/Quit Unprivileged File With Sudo

Tags: save, quit

I found the following command, which saves the current file with `sudo`, meaning you can open a file you don't have write access to (as long as you *do* have read access), in the amazing [Ultimate vimrc](https://github.com/amix/vimrc) by `amix`:

```
command W w !sudo tee % > /dev/null
```

If you stick this in your `vimrc`, then type `:W` in any open file, `vim`gives you 2 options: `Load`, which reloads the file with the new changes, and `OK`, which does not reload the file, but keeps the changes to the current buffer.

**Is there an equivalent command for saving and quitting at the same time?** It would be to `:x` what this `:W` command is to `:w`.

Comment: I couldn't find a relevant tag for the `sudo` part. `sudo` is not a tag, nor `root`, nor `privileged`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a save/quit automated, but as a reference to several nix-oriented tasks, there is a plugin that covers much of it (e.g. SudoWrite).   (plugin: [eunuch](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4300))

To combine the two tasks without using sudo you can use `:wq` of course.
I attempted using `:w !sudo tee % | q` which failed.
Using the `eunuch` plugin instead allows: `SudoWrite | q` which successfully writes and then quits.

Thus, installing that plugin and then using `:command! W SudoWrite | q` does the intended sudo-write and then quit.

Comment: better use my [SudoWrite](http://github.com/chrisbra/SudoEdit.vim/) plugin, which works on Windows and supports undofiles

Comment: Windows has something equivalent to `sudo` ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it have?

Comment: Yeah I spose any `admin` user is similar to `root`. Cool.